# Magento 2 : Add Image Field on CMS Page

Tags: magento2, cms, image-upload, cms-pages

```
Here is my code 

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/db_schema.xml


     <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
           <table name="cms_page" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="Cms Page">
              <column length="255" name="image_field" nullable="false" xsi:type="varchar"/>
           </table>
        </schema>


> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/Adminhtml/ui_component/cms_page_form.xml

    

<field name="image_field">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">cms</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Og Image Upload</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="demo/cms_heroimage/upload"/>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Cmspage/Banner/Upload.php

     <?php
         declare(strict_types=1);
         namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Cmspage\Banner;
         use Vendor\Module\\Model\BannerUploader;
         use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
         use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
         use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
         /**
           * Class Upload
         */
         class Upload extends Action
         {
        /**
        * @var string
        */
        const ACTION_RESOURCE = 
        'Vendor_Module::imageuploadfield';
        /**
        * @var BannerUploader
        */
        protected $uploader;
        /**
        * Upload constructor.
        *
        * @param Context $context
        * @param BannerUploader $uploader
        */
        public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        BannerUploader $uploader
        ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->uploader = $uploader;
        }
        /**
        * Upload file controller action
        *
        * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
        */
        public function execute()
        {
        try {
            $result = $this->uploader->saveFileToTmpDir('banner_image');
            $result['cookie'] = [
            'name'     => $this->_getSession()->getName(),
            'value'    => $this->_getSession()->getSessionId(),
            'lifetime' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieLifetime(),
            'path'     => $this->_getSession()->getCookiePath(),
            'domain'   => $this->_getSession()->getCookieDomain(),
            ];
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $result = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => $e->getCode()];
        }
        return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)->setData($result);
        }
        /**
        * @return string
        */
        protected function getFieldName()
        {
        return $this->_request->getParam('banner_image');
        }
    }
   
> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/Adminhtml/routes.xml

    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
        <router id="admin">
            <route id="demo" frontName="demo">
                <module name="vendor_module"/>
            </route>
        </router>
    </config>


> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/Adminhtml/di.xml

    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <type name="Magento\Cms\Model\PageRepository">
            <plugin name="Vendor_save_banner_image" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Cms\Model\PageRepository\BeforeSave\SaveBannerImagePlugin" />
        </type>
        
        <type name="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Cms\Model\PageRepository\BeforeSave\SaveBannerImagePlugin">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="uploader" xsi:type="object">VendorBannerUploader</argument>
            </arguments>
        </type>
        <type name="Magento\Cms\Model\Page\DataProvider">
            <plugin name="Vendor_add_banner_image_to_form" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Cms\Model\Page\DataProvider\AfterGetData\ModifyBannerDataPlugin"/>
        </type>
    </config>


>app/code/Vendor\Module\Plugin\Cms\Model\PageRepository\BeforeSave\SaveBannerImagePlugin\SaveBannerImagePlugin.php

   <?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Cms\Model\PageRepository\BeforeSave;
use Vendor\Module\Model\BannerUploader;
use Magento\Cms\Api\Data\PageInterface;
use Magento\Cms\Model\PageRepository;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
/**
 * Class SaveBannerImagePlugin
 */
class SaveBannerImagePlugin
{
    /**
     * @var BannerUploader
     */
    private $uploader;
    /**
     * @var RequestInterface
     */
    private $request;
    /**
     * SaveBannerImagePlugin constructor.
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     * @param BannerUploader $uploader
     */
    public function __construct(
        RequestInterface $request,
        BannerUploader $uploader
    ) {
        $this->uploader = $uploader;
        $this->request = $request;
    }
    /**
     * Save
     *
     * @param PageRepository $subject
     * @param PageInterface $page
     * @return array
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function beforeSave(
        PageRepository $subject,
        PageInterface $page
    ): array {

        $data = $page->getData();
        $key = 'banner_image';
        if (isset($data[$key]) && is_array($data[$key])) {
            if (!empty($data[$key]['delete'])) {
                $data[$key] = null;
            } else {
                if (isset($data[$key][0]['name']) && isset($data[$key][0]['tmp_name'])) {
                    $image = $data[$key][0]['name'];
                    $image = $this->uploader->moveFileFromTmp($image);
                    $data[$key] = $image;
                } else {
                    if (isset($data[$key][0]['url'])) {
                        $data[$key] = basename($data[$key][0]['url']);
                    }
                }
            }
            $page->setData($data);
        } else {
            $data[$key] = null;
        }
        return [$page];
    }
}


> app\code\Vendor\Module\Plugin\Cms\Model\Page\DataProvider\AfterGetData\ModifyBannerDataPlugin.php

   <?php
    declare(strict_types=1);
    namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Cms\Model\Page\DataProvider\AfterGetData;
    use Vendor\Module\Model\BannerUploader;
    use Magento\Cms\Model\Page\DataProvider;
    use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
    use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
    /**
     * Class ModifyBannerDataPlugin
     */
    class ModifyBannerDataPlugin
    {
        /**
         * @var StoreManagerInterface
         */
        private $storeManager;
        /**
         * ModifyBannerDataPlugin constructor.
         * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
         */
        public function __construct(StoreManagerInterface $storeManager)
        {
            $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        }
        /**
         * @param DataProvider $subject
         * @param $loadedData
         * @return array
         * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
         */
        public function afterGetData(
            DataProvider $subject,
            $loadedData
        ) 
        {

            /** @var array $loadedData */
            if (is_array($loadedData) && count($loadedData) == 1) 
            {
                foreach ($loadedData as $key => $item) {  
                   if (isset($item['banner_image']) && $item['banner_image']) {
                        $imageArr = [];
                        $imageArr[0]['url'] = 'Image';
                       
                        $imageArr[0]['url'] = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).BannerUploader::IMAGE_PATH.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$item['banner_image'];
                        $loadedData[$key]['banner_image'] = $imageArr;   
                    }
                }
                return $loadedData;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check this [module](https://github.com/theshreyas/magento-2-quickies/tree/main/CmsImage)